# How to connect a Forked Repository to a local repository that is hosted on heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku, fork

I hosted my react boilerplate for a team project on heroku. Now I Forked the teams project from GitHub. Now I intend connecting the project I pushed to heroku to my team project that I Forked.

Does anybody know the git command that I need to use?